# AWS - Is there a more efficient way to call another lambda from within a lambda method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

### AWS Lambda - Java currently only allows one event notification per S3 Bucket put.

So in order to simulate 2 events, I send an event to a Forwarder which then invokes the 2 other lambdas.  In order for this handoff to be successful, I have to do a wait on the result, "InvokeResult result1 = resultFuture1.get();"

This means that the forwarder has to wait until completion of the other lambdas ( and incur the billing timing cost of those other lambdas ).  Is there a better way?

```
public class Forwarder
    public String runSingleConvert(S3MKVBucketInformation bucketInformation, Context context) {
        AWSLambdaAsyncClient client = new AWSLambdaAsyncClient();
        InvokeRequest request1 = new InvokeRequest();    
        request1.setFunctionName("Receiver1");
        request1.setPayload(toByteBuffer(bucket, key));
        Future<InvokeResult> resultFuture1 = client.invokeAsync(request1);
        InvokeResult result1 = resultFuture1.get();

        InvokeRequest request2 = new InvokeRequest();    
        request2.setFunctionName("Receiver2");
        request2.setPayload(toByteBuffer(bucket, key));
        Future<InvokeResult> resultFuture2 = client.invokeAsync(request2);
        InvokeResult result2 = resultFuture2.get();
```

Comment: AWS Lambda functions can be called synchronously or asynchronously (event mode). You may want to try the latter so the call returns before the function completes. Another option is to send the event to an SNS topic and subscribe multiple Lambda functions to the topic. You can also subscribe email addresses and SQS queues to the topic.

Comment: Here's an article I wrote about connecting S3 to SNS using the aws-cli: https://alestic.com/2014/12/s3-bucket-notification-to-sqssns-on-object-creation/

Comment: I am trying to use AWSLambdaAsyncClient.  But this doesn't complete the call unless I do a get() on the result.   Thus making the whole thing synchronous

Comment: Do you have an example of doing your suggestion, " Another option is to send the event to an SNS topic and subscribe multiple Lambda functions to the topic"

Comment: This article includes an example of subscribing an AWS Lambda function to an SNS topic: https://alestic.com/2015/04/aws-cli-sns-lambda/

Comment: You seem to be using a library that calls the synchronous AWS Lambda function call, but does it asynchronously. You want to call the asynchronous invoke Lambda API. It might say something like "event" type in your parameters.